# Assigning AngularJS model inside ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to iterate over an array in AngularJS like this:

```
var languages = ['en', 'es', 'fr'];
```

To generate something like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mymodel.en" placeholder="Name (EN)">
<input type="text" ng-model="mymodel.es" placeholder="Name (ES)">
<input type="text" ng-model="mymodel.fr" placeholder="Name (FR)">
```

I have tried this:

```
<div ng-repeat="language in languages">
   <input type="text" ng-model="mymodel.{{language}}" placeholder="Name ({{language | uppercase}})">
</div>
```

But throws an error:

> "Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column ..."

How should I perform this loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mymodel[language]` instead of `mymodel.{{language}}`

```
<div ng-repeat="language in languages"> 
   <input type="text" ng-model="mymodel[language]" placeholder="Name ({{language | uppercase}})">
</div>
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uc7JJuDXp2Vggt8MHcuW?p=preview)

See the plnkr, and start typing in any of the input fields to see the model changes.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use {{}} notation inside ng-model here you can refer to your property in the mymodel object.

But it seems that you are trying to get binding via model somehow for your inputs. It's not gonna work in your case because you need to init mg-model directives.

For catching changed in your model from dynamically generated you need to compile used directives using $compile service.

Here you can check out [sample](http://goo.gl/LdAQrl). I googled it but I've solved similar problem in similar way.

Answer (score 1):

you cantry something like this,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mymodel[language]" ...
```

Comment: its working, try to print `{{mymodel | json}}` after the ng-repeat u can see the different model names inside `mymodel`